# How to store a class in local storage using jquery?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have multiple check boxes. on click their background colour changes and their value is saved to the local storage. However when refreshed the background colour is not saved. How can you save the background colour change to local storage?
here is example code i'm using https://jsfiddle.net/2m04prmz/2/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" id="like9" ><label></label>
```

CSS:

```
.pincard-checked,  pin p {
    background-color: #2c3e50; color: #ffffff;transition: all 1s ease-out;border-top:2px solid #fff; 
}
```

JS: to control the highlighting

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#like").click(function () {
        $("#pin").toggleClass("pincard-checked");
    });
});
```

JS: Saving checkbox value to local storage

```
$('.faChkRnd').on('click', function() {
    var fav, favs = [];
    $('.faChkRnd').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
        fav = {
            id: $(this).attr('id'),
            value: $(this).prop('checked')
        };
        favs.push(fav);
    });
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
    if (!favorites.length) {
        return
    };
    console.debug(favorites);

    for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
        console.debug(favorites[i].value == 'on');
        $('#' + favorites[i].id).prop('checked', favorites[i].value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the JS console?

Comment: Please remove **all irrelevant code**. Create a MCVE of the issue your having.

Comment: No errors and It's all relevant. . .

Comment: change `if (!favorites.length) {` to simply `if (!favorites) {`

Comment: you are styling this selector `.pincard-checked,  pin p ` but where are you assigning this class to the checkbox?

Comment: also, at the end of `$('#' + favorites[i].id).prop('checked', favorites[i].value);` add `...value).change()` for best results. For instance, if these checkboxes do something like change a page color when checked, and that event is assigned (as should be) to the checkbox's `change` event, then when you recheck these things on load, you want to trigger that event. also, all of your js can go into one `$(document).ready(function() {`, which in jQuery shorthand is just `$(function() { /* do work */ })`

Comment: yes, i'm styling the selector via class="faChkRnd". hmmm, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class along with checking the checkboxes when `favorites[i].value` is `true`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
    $('#' + favorites[i].id).prop('checked', favorites[i].value);
    if(favorites[i].value) {
        $('#' + favorites[i].id).closest(".pin").addClass("pincard-checked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Very slick solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the background of the checkbox you can use the following code and I have also included the local storage solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkbox-wrapper label").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".checkbox-wrapper").toggleClass('selected');
    var fav, favs = [];
    $('.faChkRnd').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes

      fav = {
        id: $(this).attr('id'),
        value: $(this).closest(".checkbox-wrapper").hasClass('selected')
      };
      favs.push(fav);
    });
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
  });


  var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  if (favorites != null && favorites.length !== 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
      if (favorites[i].value == true) {
        $('#' + favorites[i].id).closest(".checkbox-wrapper").addClass("selected")
        $('#' + favorites[i].id).closest(".checkbox-wrapper faChkRnd").trigger("click");
      }

    }
  }


});
```

```css
 .checkbox-wrapper-list li {
   display: inline;
 }
 .checkbox-wrapper-list li label {
   display: inline;
   padding-left: 50px;
   position: relative;
   left: -19px;
 }
 .checkbox-wrapper-list li span {
   position: relative;
   display: inline;
   width: 30px;
 }
 .checkbox-wrapper-list li span i {
   position: absolute;
   margin: auto;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 14px;
   height: 14px;
   border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
   border-radius: 2px;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
   background-color: #fff;
 }
 .checkbox-wrapper-list li.selected i {
   background-color: #11a911;
   box-shadow: none;
   border-color: transparent;
   background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAGCAYAAAD+Bd/7AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAABx0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgRmlyZXdvcmtzIENTNXG14zYAAABMSURBVAiZfc0xDkAAFIPhd2Kr1WRjcAExuIgzGUTIZ/AkImjSofnbNBAfHvzAHjOKNzhiQ42IDFXCDivaaxAJd0xYshT3QqBxqnxeHvhunpu23xnmAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="checkbox-wrapper-list">
  <li class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <span><i></i></span>
    <label for="like1">Like 1</label>
    <input name="your_checkbox[]" class="faChkRnd" id="like1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox">
  </li>
  <li class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <span><i></i></span>
    <label for="like2">Like 2</label>
    <input name="your_checkbox[]" class="faChkRnd" id="like2" style="display: none;" type="checkbox">
  </li>
  <li class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <span><i></i></span>
    <label for="like3">Like 3</label>
    <input name="your_checkbox[]" class="faChkRnd" id="like3" style="display: none;" type="checkbox">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Keep Hacking !